# Only Text from Items of ListView are clickable

Tags: android

We have a `ListView` with dynamic content and we can only click on the text, and not the whole item (that means a short text means a small touch area)

Our ListView:

```
ListView lv = getListView();  
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

What do we have to do to make the whole Item clickable and not only its text

Comment: You can get answer here:-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497000/width-of-clickable-area-in-listview-w-onlistitemclick

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to fullfill all the with of the listview with the textview you are using, place in its propeties:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to intercept the touch event in the parent of the textview. see [onInterceptTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29)

Answer (score 0):

Set the layout width of the **listView** to match it's parent:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Otherwise, although the row appears to be the full width of the screen, the listview actually is not.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used my ListView + ArrayAdapter within DialogFragment. All `android:layout_width` were correct.

```
val adapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, options)
        listView.adapter = adapter
```

So I changed the DialogFragment to the Fragment and it works - now entire list item is clickable...