# Width of clickable area in ListView w/ onListItemClick

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to get my list items in a ListView clickable.  At the moment they are clickable (see my screenshot) but they're only clickable within the rectangle the text takes up.

I'm using `protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {`
for the clickable list items.

Here is my list.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/android:empty"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/no_favorites"/>
```

and my row.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/artist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/songtitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/album"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/playtime"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/playlistnum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And [here's the screenshot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mxjnw.png):
(New users aren't allowed to post images... grumble... have a hyperlink!)

In list.xml, the Listview has android:layout_width="fill_parent" so it should be the full width of the screen.  (All of the items in row.xml are also width="fill_parent".)  What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The TextView in your list.xml needs to be set to fill_parent. The selection will then fit the width of the parent ListView.

```
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

Comment: Tried it, didn't work.  That TextView is only used when the list is empty. :/

Comment: hmmm.... Ah, only other difference in my code and yours would be the LinearLayout also set to fill_parent on the layout_width. Give that a try. If that doesn't work I'll open my code up and post it here.

Comment: To be clear I was referring to the LinearLayout in your list.xml in my last comment. It's set to wrap_content. Worked for me changing that to fill_parent.